# display some table rows and displays some other rows in sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, database

I have a table with the following information

| id | status | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | X |
| 101 | 2 | Y |
| 102 | 3 | Y |
| 103 | 4 | X |
| 104 | 1 | Y |

And I want to display information of some customers except customers whose status is 1 and their type X

```
select c from client c 
where c.status = 1 or c.status = 3 and c.status !=1 and c.type !=x
```

For example, in this table only show customer 101 and 102 and 104.

Thankful

Comment: Why 101, 102 and 104?

YOu don't want customers with type = 'X' and status = 1. Therefore there should remain 101, 102, 103 and 104.

Comment: Tip: Switch to standard SQL `<>` instead of that ancient`!=`. To avoid future problems.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude customers with either `c.status = 1` or `c.type = 'x'` . Columns are assumed being not nullabe.

```
select c.* 
from client c 
where c.status != 1 AND c.type != 'x'
```

or

```
select c.* 
from client c 
where NOT (c.status = 1 OR c.type = 'x')
```

Comment: I _think_ you need to switch AND/OR. (But the question is a bit unclear, so I could be wrong.)